# Scroll Background image slower relative to the HTML page

Tags: html, css

*** Edited based on various feedback***

I was trying to implement `Parallax effect` in my Webpage as described in http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Below is my HTML and CSS code :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS.css">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "Parallax/parallax.js"></script>


</head>



<body id='ground'>
  <div id='Main_Div'>
    <div id = 'Sub_Div1'>

    </div>

    <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Mytikas.jpg">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>

    <div id = 'Sub_Div3'>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}

#Main_Div {
  height: 2600px;
  background: #FFFF00;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#Sub_Div1 {
  height: 500px;
  background: #800000;
  padding: 30px 0;
}


#Sub_Div3 {
  height: 500px;
  background: #FFA500;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.parallax-window {
    height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

However with above code I could not achieve desired effect.

Appreciate if someone can point out any improvement in my code.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean what Parallax offers? http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/
Edit; Didn't see you knew it. But that's pretty much what you're after.

Comment: Here's a "Parallax" effect using only CSS3 https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ .
No javascript/jquery.